# how to create the input div on clicking the reply button of a comment below that particular comment using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want on clicking the reply button the div to write the reply to come

I tried to create a seperate component for reply textarea but as I am a beginner in react I am not able to get an idea how to do it.

Comment.js

```js
import Userdata from "./data.json";
import Score from "./Score";
import Person from "./person";
import Reply from "./Reply";

const Comment = () => {
    return (<div className="sample">{
        Userdata.comments.map((comment, index) => {
            return (
                <div key={comment.id}>
                    <div className="comment">
                        <Score score={comment.score} />
                        <div>
                            <Person user={comment.user} />
                            <span className="time">{comment.createdAt}</span>
                            <Reply index={index} />
                            <p>{comment.content}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {comment.replies.map((reply) => {
                        return (
                            <div key={reply.id}>
                                <div className="comment reply">
                                    <Score score={reply.score} />
                                    <div>
                                        <Person user={reply.user} />
                                        <span>{reply.createdAt}</span>
                                        <Reply />
                                        <p>{reply.content}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        );
                    })}
                </div>
            );
        })
    }
    </div>
    );
}
export default Comment;
```

Reply Component

```js
const Reply = (props) => {

const handleClick = () => {
    console.log(`reply of ${props.index}`)
}
return (
    <div onClick= {handleClick} className="btn-reply">
        <img className="reply-icon" src="images/icon-reply.svg" alt="reply" />
        <span>Reply</span>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Reply;
```